# Show that $(x-a)^T(x-a)=\text{tr}(x_c, x_c)+n(a-\bar x)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, quadratic-forms, trace

Show that $(x-a)^T(x-a)=\text{tr}(x_c, x_c)+n(a-\bar x)^2$ (Gentle Matrix Algebra exercise 3.2)

This shows that the norm $\|x-a\|$ is minimized when $a=\bar x$.

I went through the pages and got the relevant equations:

- $x^Tx=\text{tr}(xx^T)$
- $x_c=x-\bar x$
- $\bar x=1^Tx/n$

The solution says "This exercise occurs in many guises in many different places, and the simple approach is to add and subtract $\bar x$:

$$\begin{split}(x-a)^T(x-a)&=(x-\bar x-(a-\bar x))^T(x-\bar x-(a-\bar x))\\
&=(x_c-(a-\bar x))^T(x_c-(a-\bar x))\\
&=x_c^Tx_c+(a-\bar x)^T(a-\bar x)-2(a-\bar x)^Tx_c\\
&=\text{tr}(x_cx_c^T)+n(a-\bar x)^2\color{red}{-2(a-\bar x)^Tx_c}\end{split}$$

Finally, we get the expression by writing $x_c^Tx_c$ as $\text{tr}(x_cx_c^T)$. (I did this in the last step.) Question: where does the red part go? It doesn't look like it equals $0$ to me, but it is omitted in the last step (i.e. the red part disappears in the solution).

Comment: You need to be careful here, the notation is a bit sloppy, in that you have some quantities that are scalars that are being treated like vectors, and so the definitions you have are NOT correct.  In particular, you do not want to be taking $\overline{x}=1^Tx/n$, but rather $(1^Tx)1/n$, where $1$ is the vector that is 1 in all the components.  Similarly, a isn't really a, but rather a1.  Abuse of notation can be useful sometimes, but here it is hiding something essential.  Always ask "what types of objects do I have, and am I making a type error?" If so, you have more notation to unravel.

Comment: That’s how it’s written in the book, $\bar x=1_n^T x/n$. Besides, wouldn’t you get the same quantity whether you divided the entries first or after the inner product? This book says that it is not supposed to be notationally rigorous, inferring scalars and vectors from the context.

Comment: It’s not about when you divide by n, it’s about multiplying by the vector 1. Whenever you add a scalar to a vector, you aren’t actually adding a scalar, you are multiplying by (1,1,1,1,….) and then adding that vector. If you want to understand what is going on here, you need to be very explicit about that.

Comment: It is skipped in the book. “If ‘c’ denotes a scalar constant, we may refer to the vector all of whose elements are c as ‘c’ also.” So $0_n,1_n,c_n$ skips the step of representing it as $c1_n$. But I do see it usually represented your way online.

Comment: You can write it any way you choose, but at the end of the day, you need the fact that (in your notation) $1^Tx_c=0$, and this notation both makes it non-obvious that this is what you need AND obscures how to show it.

Comment: I don’t think I understand your point. Isn’t it obvious it’s the inner product of two vectors producing a scalar? Edit: oh I see your point. But I don’t agree, we can still do the whole $(a-\bar x)^Tx_c$ without ever knowing the $1$-vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a-\bar{x}$ is a constant. Any constant multiplying $x_c$ will not change the fact that $x_c$ is centred, so the scaled sum will still be $0$.